# Get address of buffer for video capture

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ioctl

I am trying to use python to capture an image from a camera.

I have been looking at the capture example code, which is in c, on [linuxtv.org](https://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis-new/userspace-api/v4l/capture.c.html), and I've got to a bit of an impasse.

I'm using the `USERPTR` IO method, because mmap seems too complicated and I can't use the read method.

In the original c there is a struct like so:

```c
struct buffer {
        void   *start;
        size_t  length;
};
```

Which I have pythonised into:

```py
class buffer_location():
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = v4l2.c_int(0)
        self.length = 0
```

Where `v4l2` is a python module that wraps up linux/videodev2.h

In order to initialise the buffers for the video capture I have done this:

```py
buflocs = []
buffers = []
buffer_size = ...#size is taken from another ioctl call

for i in range(4):
  bl = buffer_location()
  buflocs.append(bl)
  bl.length = buffer_size
  buff = create_string_buffer(buffer_size)
  buffers.append(buff)
  bl.start = pointer(buff)
```

This is an attempt to replicate what happens in `init_userp` in the original c. Then I tried to replicate `start_capturing` like so:

```py
for i in range(4):
  v4l2buf = v4l2.v4l2_buffer()
  v4l2buf.type = v4l2.V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE
  v4l2buf.memory = v4l2.V4L2_MEMORY_USERPTR
  v4l2buf.index = i
  v4l2buf.m.usrptr = buflocs[i].start
  v4l2buf.length = buffer_size

  if -1 == ioctl(cam, v4l2.VIDIOC_QBUF, v4l2buf):
    print('cannot qbuf')
```

However this gives the error

> OSError: [Errno 14] Bad address

I assume this is coming from `v4l2buf.m.usrptr`.

How can I correctly assign the address to the start of the buffer?

Comment: What is your `pointer` function doing?

Comment: also curious what create_string_buffer is doing

Comment: @Carson these are both functions from the ctypes library: [pointer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.pointer), [create_string_buffer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.create_string_buffer)

Comment: Does replacing `v4l2buf` with `pointer(v4l2buf)` change anything?

Comment: @Carson in the end I wrote the function in c and import it into python. not exactly what I wanted, but better than pulling my hair out.